# Python web-server usage in docker to answer the post requests with the ML model

Tags: python, docker, post, keras, webserver

I'm trying to take POST request, parse it, call model method to get a prediction on given data.
And after that give the prediction back or print on web-server.

So far I can get POST answer with some text I wrote in the json file I give(checked with Insomnia).

Docker Toolbox from time to time doesn't allow me to run web-server but I don't understand, which mistake I make. All the necessary libraries I ask to install beforehand in Dockerfile.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import socket
import subprocess
from io import BytesIO

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from urllib import request, parse

# HTTPRequestHandler class
class testHTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

  # GET
    def do_GET(self):
        # Send response status code
        self.send_response(200)

        # Send headers
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, world!')
        # Send message back to client
        message = "<font size=+3>Hello world!(HTML)</font><p>"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) #  Gets the size of data
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)  # - Gets the data itself
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b'wto proishodit????. ')
        response.write(b'This is POST request. ')
        response.write(b'Received: ')
        response.write(body)
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())

def run():
    print('starting server...')

   # Server settings
   # Choose port 8081, for port 80, which is normally used for a http server, you need root access
    server_address = ('', 8888)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, testHTTPServer_RequestHandler)
    print('running server...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

class modelnn(object):
    """docstring"""

    def __init__(self,data):
        """Constructor"""
        self.data = data

  def get_result(self):
        train = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1,0]])
        train.columns = ['ohe1', 'ohe2','ohe3', 'output']
        X_train = train[['ohe1', 'ohe2','ohe3']]
        y_train = train['output']

        batch_size = 2
        epochs = 6
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(3,)))  
        model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))  
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=0); 

        a = model.predict(self.data)
        b =np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: round(x[0]), 1, a )
        return b


X_test = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 0]])
X_test.columns = ['ohe1', 'ohe2','ohe3']
resultat = modelnn(X_test)
b = resultat.get_result() 


run()
```

I've tried to use json.loads(body) on post request to parse it, but it didn't work out.

The post request in input.json is something like that: '{"a": [2,2,2]}'.

Using Docker Toolbox I create an image and then run it:

```
docker build -t server .
docker run -t -p 8888:8888 server
```

I assume, I do something wrong with Docker or maybe I don't fully get the logic, so any help will be very useful. Thanks!

https://github.com/dwfjwedk/webserver.git

Comment: please share the error you get when running the docker run command

Comment: I actually don't have the error, but the problem is, that from time to time my webserver exits right after the start. 
But if I remove the part that involves keras, everything I wrote works just fine.

Comment: So far, main question is, if the logic is correct and how to use data from post request as test data for the keras model

Comment: I need more information. please try to reproduce the issue. once you have a clear steps to reproduce the unexpected exit try to keep the container logs. using the command `docker logs -f <container name>`

Comment: Thank you, Mickey! I've found the problem and now I'm going to find out how to parse and use post request body!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mostly related to wrong usage of space and tabs, and also the text for .json request.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from io import BytesIO
import json
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class testHTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        message = "<font size=+3>Hello world!</font><p>"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) 
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)  
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b'This is POST request.\n')
        response.write(b'Received as a test data: ')
        response.write(body)        
        response.write(b'\nPredicted by nn model:')
        X_test = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(body.decode('utf-8')).values())        
        resultat = modelnn(X_test)

        b = resultat.get_result()
        response.write(str(b).encode('UTF-8'))
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())

def run():
    print('starting server...')
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, testHTTPServer_RequestHandler)
    print('running server...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

class modelnn(object):

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def get_result(self):
        train = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1,0]])
        train.columns = ['ohe1', 'ohe2','ohe3', 'output']
        X_train = train[['ohe1', 'ohe2','ohe3']]
        y_train = train['output']

        batch_size = 2
        epochs = 6
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(3,)))  
        model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))  
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=0); 

        a = model.predict(self.data)
        b =np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: round(x[0]), 1, a )
        return b

run()
```